# How to disable language embedding in URLs in Sitecore?

Tags: url, sitecore, sitecore6

After setting up a simple Sitecore site, links to pages sometimes contain the current language:

```
http://example.com/item.aspx
http://example.com/en/item.aspx
```

I would like to disable this behavior so that all links point to `http://example.com/item.aspx` without the language as part of the path. How can this be done?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The web.config has a configuration setting for `<linkManager>` where the `languageEmbedding` option can be configured:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="sitecore" ... languageEmbedding="asNeeded" ... />
    </providers>
</linkManager>
```

The `languageEmbedding` options are:

- asNeeded
- always
- never

Changing the config to use `languageEmbedding="never"` will stop the language from showing up in the URL, and likewise `languageEmbedding="always"` will force the language to always show up in the URL.

Comment: what will asNeeded do? Correct me if i'm wrong - my research so far suggests that it's a placeholder telling sitecore you'll create your own linkmanager to check whether it's needed. The default Sitecore linkmanager treats it the same as never.

Comment: `asNeeded` embeds language when no language cookie is found

Answer (score 11):

You should not use the "asNeeded" option as it might cause multiple urls for the same pages. Use either "never" or "always" which is much more SEO-friendly